# The proper Django way to make a form field required on CreateView, but optional on UpdateView?

Tags: python, django, generics

Let's say I create an model `MyModel` instance that has a `FileField` using `CreateView` and associated `MyModelCreateForm`, and now I want to update it without uploading the same avatar image:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    avatar = models.ImageField()

class MyModelCreateForm(forms.ModeForm):
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         exclude = None

class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelCreateForm

class MyModelCreate(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = ?
```

On the CreateView's form the image is compulsory. If I want to make it optional on the update field, what's the most Django-ish way of doing this?

Do I need to make a new form for the UpdateView that inherits from `MyModelCreateForm` but overrides the ImageField `required` attribute? Or is there a more "batteries-included" way?

Comment: i think you new a new form or the form have an argument to control the logic in it: MyModelCreateForm(update=True)

Answer (score 11):

Here a solution to make a field required :

```
class Foo(CreateView):

    model = Fiz
    fields = ('bar',)

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(Foo, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['bar'].required = True
        return form
```

Answer (score 0):

i think no but you can implement in it !

```
class ModelXForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = x
    fields = ['image','name']

    def __init__(self,update, survey, **kwargs):
        super(FBRequestForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if not update:
            self.fields['image'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['image'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```